# how to generate the view by code with your required query in drupal?

Tags: php, arguments, drupal-views

I wanted to create a filter for view but that filter is taking value from user.

I tried arguments for doing this but not succeeded.

So I just got idea that I can directly use query to filter my view.

how can I render druapl's view by coding with my own query in drupal?

Answer (score 0):

I think manually queries you are not allowed to use. but for user filter you can "expose" the database fields so exposed fields are displayed at the "view"-page in a form where the user can enter the wanted data, or select it if the exposed field is for example a language field.

Comment: But is there any way alter the query before rendering the view?

Comment: You could find this out by your self. Just search this question to google. You will see: http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7 and the hook: hook_views_query_substitutions which is descriped as "Performs replacements in the query before being performed." Think this is exactly what you want or?